# Using dependent name in base class name without "typename"

Tags: c++, typename

I have a template class for which the base class is also a template parameterized with a type member of one of the outer template type parameters. Example:

```
template <typename X>
class Adapter : public Generator<typename X::generated_type>{
    using G = typename X::generated_type;
};
```

Here `X` is some type that has a member `generated_type` and we want to subclass a `Generator` for `X::generated_type`. Because `X::generated_type` is a dependent name, we have to prefix it with `typename` when we use it in the base class name.

In the rest of the definition of `Adapter`, I can use `G` instead of `typename X::generated_type`, which is obviously a lot more convenient.

Is there any way to use `G` in the name of the base class too?

In the actual code it's not this simple; I've tried to distill the example down to the core issue.

The only thing I could think of was to have `G` as a template parameter and create a wrapper that passes `X::generated_type` as `G`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to cheat, something along these lines:

```
template <typename X, typename G=typename X::generated_type>
class Adapter : public Generator<G>{
   // ...
};
```

You were almost there, heading into an additional template parameter territory, but you don't need to explicitly pass it in, just default it.

Complete example:

```
template<typename> class Generator {};

template <typename X, typename G=typename X::generated_type>
    class Adapter : public Generator<G>{
       // ...
    };

struct Y {
    typedef int generated_type;
};

int main()
{
    Adapter<Y> a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but maybe I didn't do it correctly and just assumed it wouldn't work.

Comment: Okay, it does work! Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I can't accept your answer yet, have to wait a few min.

Comment: Other way would be for Generator provide that type , or have a type trait class

Comment: By having `Generator` provide the type, I assume you mean a `typedef` or `using` in `Generator` that exposes `G`. But I don't think that helps avoid the need to use `typename` when declaring the `Generator` base class.